# Node не считывает файл с базой данных

Tags: node.js, mongodb, telegram, mongoose

Пишу бота для Телеграма, бот должен присылать цитаты пользователю. Базу создал в МонгоДБ. Проблема возникла в том что не считывало схему. Проблема решилась тогда когда перенес схему в основной файл(`index.js`). Но тогда основной файл был слишком загружен( как мне кажется).Собственно клепаю бота по образу и подобию, бота присылающего анекдоты(исходники скину как найду линк).

**Собственно проблема**: есть 3 файла  `index.js`,`models.js`, `quotebase.json`.

И проблема тут :`database.quotes.forEach(element => { new Quote(element).save() .catch(element=>console.log(element))});`

- Если запустить основной файл. вылезет **ошибка(1)** что, мол, Quote не задан.(хотя файл `models.js`, подключен)
- Если изменить строку :

***Из:***

`database.quotes.forEach(element => { new Quote(element).save() .catch(element=>console.log(element))});`
***На:***

`models.database.quotes.forEach(element => { new Quote(element).save() .catch(element=>console.log(element))});`

будет **ошибка(2)**

**Ошибка(1):**

```
ReferenceError: Quote is not defined
```

**Ошибка(2):**

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'quotes' of undefined
```

**Вопрос: Где я не прав, И как исправить обе ошибки?**

**КОД:**

***`quotebase.json`***

```
{
    "quotes":[
        {
          "text":"Scientia potentia est",
          "id": 1
        },
        {
          "text":"Divide et impero",
          "id": 2

        },
        {
           "text":"Alea iacta est",
           "id": 3
        }

    ]


}
```

***`models.js`***

```
module.exports = function () {
    const mongoose = require('mongoose')
    const mongoosactic =require('mongoosastic')
    const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var quoteSchema = new Schema({
    text: String,
    id: Number
})

 const Quote = mongoose.model('Quote',quoteSchema)


};
```

***`index.js`***

```
const mongoose= require('mongoose');
const model= require('./models')
const connect =require ('./mongoconnect.js')
const database = require('./quotebase')

database.quotes.forEach(element => { new Quote(element).save() .catch(element=>console.log(element))});
```

//дальше код по боту, как доделаю выложу на Гитхаб.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я решил проблему  заменив в файле `models.js` строку :

```
const Quote = mongoose.model('Quote',quoteSchema)
```

на 2 строки 
mongoose.model('Quote',quoteSchema) //  в файле ***`models.js`***

И

`const Quote = mongoose.model('Quote')` // в файле ***`index.js`***

И Всё.